# How to align multiple long equations between them and inside them

Tags: equations, align, split

I have the following series of equations:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}\label{eq:1}
 V_{g}(L^V_g, L^V_g) = {}& \pi_{gt}^{\ominus}\bigg[(1-L^V_g)^{1-\alpha} P_{jt}(N_{gt}r_{gt})^{\alpha} + (1-L^V_{\bar{g}})^{1-\alpha} P_{\overline{j}t}(N_{\bar{g}t}r_{\bar{g}t})^{\alpha} + \delta V_t^V(.)\bigg] \\ & - w_{gt}^F(1-L^V_g) - w_{gt}^V L^V_g 
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}\label{eq:2}
 V_{g}(L^V_g, 0) = {}& \pi_{gt}\bigg[(1-L^V_g)^{1-\alpha} P_{jt}(N_{gt}r_{gt})^{\alpha} + (1-L^V_{\bar{g}})^{1-\alpha} P_{\overline{j}t}(N_{\bar{g}t}r_{\bar{g}t})^{\alpha} + \delta V_t^V(.)\bigg] \\ & - w_{gt}^F(1-L^V_g) - w_{gt}^V L^V_g 
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}\label{eq:3}
 V_{g}(0, L^V_g) = {}& (1-\pi_{\bar{g}t})\bigg[(1-L^V_g)^{1-\alpha} P_{jt}(N_{gt}r_{gt})^{\alpha} + (1-L^V_{\bar{g}})^{1-\alpha} P_{\overline{j}t}(N_{\bar{g}t}r_{\bar{g}t})^{\alpha} + \delta V_t^V(.)\bigg] \\ & - w_{gt}^F(1-L^V_g) - w_{gt}^V L^V_g 
\end{split} \\
\begin{split}\label{eq:4}
V_{g}(0, 0) = {}& P_{jt}(N_{gt}r_{gt})^{\alpha} + \delta V_t^P(g) - w_{gt}^F + H_{gt}(\mathbb{1}_{\epsilon_{gt}})
\end{split} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

which gives me the following result:

[image]

But I would like the following output:

[image]

I would like the `$V_{gt}(.)$` to be aligned to the left while keeping an alignment also inside each equation. In my example, the equations are aligned with respect to "=": when I split an equation, the new part is aligned with respect to "=" but my problem is that the equations are aligned with respect to "=" also between them. However I would like that each equation is aligned with respect to "=" (so that an equation is correctly split) but I would like also that the equations are aligned to the left between them (the `$V_{gt}(.)$`). Unfortunately, I found no answer to my problem.

I hope I am clear enough. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Welcome to the site.  The `align` family of environments always employ right-left alignments, whereas you seem to want left alignments only.  Perhaps `align` is the wrong tool.

Comment: You can do this using `alignat` but it is going to require a lot of `&` per line, so I'm not sure that it is worth it

Comment: BTW, you might want to put the equation number on the last line of each equation instead of the first.  See \notag.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your welcoming and for your remarks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that with `alignedat` and `aligned`.  Note I had to change the fontsize to 11pt and set horizontal margins to 1in to make the equations fit within margins. Also, unless your distribution is quite old, loading `inputenc` with option `utf8` is not necessary nowadays: it has been  the default for more than 3 years.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\label{eq:1}
 & V_{g}(L^V_g, L^V_g) & & = \begin{aligned}[t] & \pi_{gt}^{\ominus}\bigg[(1-L^V_g)^{1-\alpha} P_{jt}(N_{gt}r_{gt})^{\alpha} + (1-L^V_{\bar{g}})^{1-\alpha} P_{\overline{j}t}(N_{\bar{g}t}r_{\bar{g}t})^{\alpha} + \delta V_t^V(.)\bigg] \\ & - w_{gt}^F(1-L^V_g) - w_{gt}^V L^V_g
\end{aligned}\\
\label{eq:2}
 & V_{g}(L^V_g, 0) & & = \begin{aligned}[t]& \pi_{gt}\bigg[(1-L^V_g)^{1-\alpha} P_{jt}(N_{gt}r_{gt})^{\alpha} + (1-L^V_{\bar{g}})^{1-\alpha} P_{\overline{j}t}(N_{\bar{g}t}r_{\bar{g}t})^{\alpha} + \delta V_t^V(.)\bigg] \\ & - w_{gt}^F(1-L^V_g) - w_{gt}^V L^V_g
\end{aligned}\\
\label{eq:3}
 & V_{g}(0, L^V_g) & & = \begin{aligned}[t]& (1-\pi_{\bar{g}t})\bigg[(1-L^V_g)^{1-\alpha} P_{jt}(N_{gt}r_{gt})^{\alpha} + (1-L^V_{\bar{g}})^{1-\alpha} P_{\overline{j}t}(N_{\bar{g}t}r_{\bar{g}t})^{\alpha} + \delta V_t^V(.)\bigg] \\ & - w_{gt}^F(1-L^V_g) - w_{gt}^V L^V_g
\end{aligned} \\
\label{eq:4}
 & V_{g}(0, 0) & & =P_{jt}(N_{gt}r_{gt})^{\alpha} + \delta V_t^P(g) - w_{gt}^F + H_{gt}(\mathbb{1}_{\epsilon_{gt}})
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly !

Answer (score 2):

I used `alignat` and additional `&` separators to achieve the left alignments.  I changed `split` to `aligned` probably out of personal preference, and I had to add a `\!` before the 2nd line of the `aligned` equations, to back up the minus sign into alignment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
\label{eq:1}
& V_{g}(L^V_g, L^V_g) &&= \begin{aligned}[t]{}& \pi_{gt}^{\ominus}
 \bigg[(1-L^V_g)^{1-\alpha} P_{jt}(N_{gt}r_{gt})^{\alpha} + 
 (1-L^V_{\bar{g}})^{1-\alpha} P_{\overline{j}t}(N_{\bar{g}t}r_{\bar{g}t})^{\alpha} 
 + \delta V_t^V(.)\bigg] 
 \\ & \!- w_{gt}^F(1-L^V_g) - w_{gt}^V L^V_g 
\end{aligned}\\
\label{eq:2}
& V_{g}(L^V_g, 0) &&= \begin{aligned}[t]{}& \pi_{gt}\bigg[(1-L^V_g)^{1-\alpha}
 P_{jt}(N_{gt}r_{gt})^{\alpha} + (1-L^V_{\bar{g}})^{1-\alpha} P_{\overline{j}t}
 (N_{\bar{g}t}r_{\bar{g}t})^{\alpha} + \delta V_t^V(.)\bigg] 
 \\ & \!- w_{gt}^F(1-L^V_g) - w_{gt}^V L^V_g 
\end{aligned}\\
\label{eq:3}
& V_{g}(0, L^V_g) &&= \begin{aligned}[t]{}& (1-\pi_{\bar{g}t})
 \bigg[(1-L^V_g)^{1-\alpha} P_{jt}(N_{gt}r_{gt})^{\alpha} + 
 (1-L^V_{\bar{g}})^{1-\alpha} P_{\overline{j}t}(N_{\bar{g}t}r_{\bar{g}t})^{\alpha}
 + \delta V_t^V(.)\bigg]
 \\ & \!- w_{gt}^F(1-L^V_g) - w_{gt}^V L^V_g 
\end{aligned} \\
\label{eq:4}
& V_{g}(0, 0) &&= \begin{aligned}[t]{}& P_{jt}(N_{gt}r_{gt})^{\alpha} + 
 \delta V_t^P(g) - w_{gt}^F + H_{gt}(\mathbb{1}_{\epsilon_{gt}})
\end{aligned} 
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the trick !